# Generate file descriptor set (.desc) with scalapb

Tags: scalapb

I am using scalapb in a project that needs to have access to the FileDescriptorSet. Is there a way to have scalapb generate the .desc file in addition to all other class files?  Or is there some programatic way of obtaining a FileDescriptorSet from what is already generated?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, to both questions.

If you are using `sbt-protoc`, you can have the following definition in your SBT file:

```
PB.protocOptions in Compile := Seq(
    "--descriptor_set_out=" + 
        (baseDirectory in Compile).value.getParentFile / "src" / "main" / "resources" /"out.desc"
)
```

One caveat is that you would have to create `src/main/resources` yourself, otherwise you would get an error. It would probably be better to generate into `resourceManaged` (that would also require creating a directory ahead of time, since `protoc` doesn't do that)

You can also build a FileDescriptorSet at run time. For each proto file, ScalaPB generates a Scala object with `scalaDescriptor` (and also `javaDescriptor` if that's more convenient). The descriptors contains a list of their dependencies which are also `FileDesciptor`s - you can traverse that tree structure and build a list of `FileDescriptor`s which is essentially a `FileDescriptorSet`.

Comment: In the rare case someone else looks for a way to generate only the `FileDescriptorSet`, `sbt-protoc` happens to provide a generator for that purpose: `Compile / PB.targets += (PB.gens.descriptorSet -> (Compile / crossTarget).value / "my.fds")`